# Routing Data from IoT Hub to Time Series Insight

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-timeseries-insights

We have setup an IoT Hub that receives telemetry data.
Current workflow route:

IoTHub -> Stream Analytics -> Event Hub -> Time Series Insight

Required workflow route:

IoTHub -> Time Series Insight

Is this possible? If yes can someone please point to a resource or suggest.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an azure portal for adding a *New event source*, see the following screen snippet:
[image]

**Note:** Before the above step, go to the Azure IoT Hub for adding a new consumer group dedicated only for this TSI consumer, see he following screen snippet:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes possible, screen shots above are great. no need to use stream or event hub unless you're looking to set up a real time process or filter what gets stored in time series.